# Is there a special name for a measure over a power set?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, definition

I have a set $\mathcal{L}$ and I want to study measures over $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{L})$ or $2^\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: While you do ask a (terminology) question in the title, there isn't any question in the body of your Question.  Please make the problem statement self-contained in the body of your Question so that Readers can respond in a concrete fashion.  As stated there seems to be no structure to the set $\mathcal{L}$ that would related to the required "measure", so explaining what motivates your interest would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The power set is just the underlying set you're defining your measure for.

You could give any measure you come up with any name that you like.

Answer (score 1):

I never came across a special name for a measure specifically defined over a power set.

Further I don't really think this would be necessary since all you need for a measure $\mu$ is essentially a $\sigma$-algebra of some kind - which the power set most certainly always is - I would always make it clear in context (if important) what kind of $\sigma$-algebra I am using.

The closest thing I can think of - where the $\sigma$-algebra as a power set is part of the definition - is the *outer measure* ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure)). So you could call your measure $\mu$ a *$\sigma-additive$ outer measure*.